# Как сделать анимацию кнопки?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Надо сделать анимацию кнопки, которая состоит из трех этапов:

1. кнопка начинает поворачиваться на 90 градусов
2. во время поворота кнопка плавно меняет картинку
3. когда поворот завершен, кнопка должна увеличится

Я сделал это через core animation.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation   animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(M_PI/2)];
[animation setDuration:kDefaultDuration];
[animation setBeginTime:0.0];


CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
crossFade.fromValue = (id)image1.CGImage;
crossFade.toValue = (id)image2.CGImage;
[crossFade setDuration:0.1];
[crossFade setBeginTime:0.1];

CAKeyframeAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation
                                       animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
NSArray *scaleValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DScale(layer.transform, 1, 1, 1)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DScale(layer.transform, 1.5, 1.5, 1)], nil];
[scaleAnimation setValues:scaleValues];
[scaleAnimation setDuration:0.2];
[scaleAnimation setBeginTime:0.1];


CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
[group setDuration:kDefaultDuration];
group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
group.autoreverses = NO;
[group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:animation,crossFade, scaleAnimation, nil]];

[layer addAnimation:group forKey:nil];
```

Проблемы: когда картинки меняются видно этот переход, одна быстро пропадает, другая в этот момент появляется, после поворота, когда начинается увеличение, картинка возвращается в исходное положение, а должна остаться в положении после поворота. Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: сделайте duration у crossFade дольше; после того, как анимация изменения картинки закончилась вручную поставьте новую картинку на кнопку

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko смена картинки теперь работает лучше, а как сделать так чтобы картинки при увеличении не возвращалась в исходное положение?

Comment: то же самое - после анимации, поставьте вручную новый размер

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Сделайте это ответом, я отмечу как правильный. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По дефолту, `CABasicAnimation` убирает все модификации лэйера, когда заканчивается. Другими словами, когда анимация закончена, все возвращается в то же состояние, что и до анимации. Чтобы это побороть, можно в момент окончания анимации всем задействованным объектам вручную присваивать новые координаты/размеры и т.д.